# Tools/Tips to determine Error Location in configure stage - PHP Extension Coding

Tags: c, debugging, syntax-error, php-extension

I was trying to code a PHP Extension in C
After `phpize` , I did `./configure` and got this error

```
checking Whether extensionB is enabled... yes, shared
./configure: line 4171: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
./configure: line 4171: ;'
```

How am I supposed to locate the line that caused the error? Any tools for this?

**Folder Structure**

```
extensionB
         config.m4
         extensionB.c
         extensionB.h
```

config.m4

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(extensionB, Whether extensionB is enabled, [--enable-extensionB enable extensionB support])

if $PHP_EXTENSIONB != "no" then
    PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(extensionB,extensionB.c,$ext_shared);
fi
```

extensionB.h

```
#ifndef PHP_EXTENSIONB_H
#define PHP_EXTENSIONB_H 1

#define PHP_EXTENSIONB_VERSION "1.0"
#define PHP_EXTENSIONB_EXTNAME "extensionB"

PHP_FUNCTION(extensionBFn1);

extern zend_module_entry extensionB_module_entry;
#define phpext_extensionB_ptr &extensionB_module_entry

#endif
```

extensionB.c

```
#include "php.h"
#include "extensionB.h"

static function_entry extensionBFns[] = 
{
 PHP_FE(extensionBFn1,NULL)
 {NULL,NULL,NULL}
};

zend_module_entry extensionB_module_entry = 
{
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
    PHP_EXTENSIONB_EXTNAME,
    extensionBFns,
    NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
    PHP_EXTENSIONB_VERSION,
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

#ifdef COMPILE_DL_EXTENSIONB
    ZEND_GET_MODULE(extensionB)
#endif

PHP_FUNCTION(extensionB)
{ 
  RETURN_STRING("Extension B returns a string from Fn 1",1);
}
```

**EDIT**

Going through my code I realised my file config.m4 should contain

```
if test "$PHP_EXTENSIONB" != "no";
then
```

NOw it passes ./configure stage, but is there any tool to show the location. like gdb?

Comment: If you put the `if` and `then` on separate lines you don't need the semicolon. You need it though if on the same line like `if test "$PHP_EXTENSIONB" != "no"; then`.

Comment: Are there any tools that will show the line which gave the error as well . The error says line 4171, which is the 3rd line of my .m4 file. 

How will i know how many lines ./configure crosses before it starts  with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing like GDB for this, but the configure.log file : search for the test that fails, and in the lines around that, it tells you what was executed exactly and what failed.